# Setting Delegate to self PaperFoldMenuController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on getting this [PaperFoldMenuController](https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFoldMenuController) going and though it is working fine, I am getting an error when setting `foldMenuViewController.delegate = self` that I am `Assigning to 'id<PaperFoldMenuControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'DOAppDelgate *const__strong'`. I am assigning it in exactly the same place as the demo which seems to run fine. Any ideas?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  DOMasterViewController *controller = (DOMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
  controller.managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

  foldMenuViewController = [[DOMenuViewController alloc] initWithMenuWidth:200 numberOfFolds:5];
  foldMenuViewController.delegate = self;
  [self.window setRootViewController:foldMenuViewController];

  NSMutableArray* viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];
  [viewControllers addObject:navigationController];
  [viewControllers addObject:controller];

  [foldMenuViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need your class to implement the protocol: `PaperFoldMenuControllerDelegate`

```
@interface DOAppDelgate()<PaperFoldMenuControllerDelegate>
- (BOOL)paperFoldMenuController:(PaperFoldMenuController *)paperFoldMenuController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (BOOL)paperFoldMenuController:(PaperFoldMenuController *)paperFoldMenuController shouldFoldMenuToRevealViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (void)paperFoldMenuController:(PaperFoldMenuController *)paperFoldMenuController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
@end
```

... then implement those methods.

edit: changed implementation to interface, mybad.